# Is there a way to make a redstone current wait a certain amount of time before transfering?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

For a map I'm making, it says "5, 4, 3, 2, 1, Go!", then it's supposed to wait a certain time, maybe... 2 minutes before it says "3, 2 , 1, GAME OVER!"

Is there a way to do this without repeaters? I tried to do it with repeaters, but it wasn't holding out long enough.

Thanks

Comment: ...more repeaters?

Comment: Repeaters aren't gonna work. Either that, or I pretty much redo all the redstone and command blocks ._.

Comment: Quick idea: if you want a time of 5 mins you could make a dispenser drop an item on a pressure plate with a NOT gate attached so that when it despawns it will emit a current.

Comment: a NOT gate?  what?

Comment: Put a redstone torch on the side of the block with the pressure plate on it

Comment: ohh you could've just said that xD

Comment: It might be a good idea to learn your logic gates. NOT, AND, OR, XOR, XAND, etc. They are the basics of redstoning and will get you a long way.

Comment: @xXPikminXx [This](http://www.ee.surrey.ac.uk/Projects/CAL/digital-logic/gatesfunc/index.html) isn't specifically about Minecraft but explains logic gates better than the Minecraft wiki does. Definitely worth a read.